# Linear Regression: Need to clarify the Coef*Feature meaning

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

Could anybody please explain if I have the Dependent Variable, e.g. outcome (y), which is defined by

```
y = K1*F1 + K2*F2 + ... + Kn*Fn + E
```

per n feature where K - coefficient, F - features (both categorical and continuous), E - error

then does it mean that `K1*F1` is the outcome per 1 feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**
Yes, that's what it means (if you don't consider `E`).

**Long Answer:**
See below a code I just did on Jupyter.

As you can see I generate some data with some "noise" then fit it with `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`. Then I get my coefficient (+intercept) and you see that the regression is actually x.coeff+intercept which is your `K1*F1` if I'm right

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

noise = 2

lr = LinearRegression()
x, y = [], []
i=0
while i<10:
    for j in range(np.random.randint(1,5)):
        x.append(i)
        y.append(i+np.random.rand()*noise+(noise/2))
    i+=np.random.rand()

%matplotlib inline
plt.scatter(x, y)

x = np.asarray(x).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.asarray(y).reshape(-1)

lr.fit(x,y)
plt.plot(x, np.multiply(x, lr.coef_[0])+lr.intercept_)
```

[image: Linear Regression]

Comment: I hope, your statement is valid, but not sure though :)

Comment: Edited to argue a bit :)

Comment: Thanks, visual answer is much better ;)